# Why does TS allow interface defined function parameters to be extended to more types?

Tags: typescript

Through the following example, it can be seen that the range of `type` has become `wider` in the implementation of `Worker1` and `Worker2`.But in Worker3, ts reported an error and did not allow `type` to become `narrower`.I don't know how to explain the status of Work0.

I think the type of say function implemented by subclasses can only be `(type: "a" | "b"): void` `(type: "a"): void` `(type: "b"): void`.

```js
interface Person {
  say(type: "a" | "b") : void;
}

class Worker0 implements Person {
  say() {}
}

class Worker1 implements Person {
  say(type: string) {}
}

class Worker2 implements Person {
  say(type: "a" | "b" | "c") {}
}

class Worker3 implements Person {
  // index.ts:19:3 - error TS2416: Property 'say' in type 'Worker3' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Person'.
  say(type: "a" | "c") {}
}
```

Comment: Optional parameters are optional

Comment: Functions are *contravariant* in their parameter types. [See these examples](https://tsplay.dev/mxEyGW) for why.  It has to do with [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll either write an answer or find a duplicate target. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz [it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) can explain Worker0, Worker2, and Worker3, but he cannot explain Worker1.

Comment: A `Person()`'s `say()` method will either be passed an `"a"` or a `"b"`. As long as the implementation would either accept or ignore an `"a"` or a `"b"`, everything is fine. (`Worker0` ignores its input, while `Worker1` and `Worker2` are happy with inputs that include both `"a"` and `"b`".) If it *explodes* when given an `"a"` or a `"b"`, then that's a problem.  Only `Worker3` would possibly explode in that situation.  My examples demonstrated the lack of issue for `Worker1`, and my links showed the documentation. In what *specific* way does it fail to explain `Worker1`?

Comment: @jcalz.I overlooked that `string` contains both "a" and "b".Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @jcalz please feel free to write your answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, function types are *contravariant* in their input parameter types.  See [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for relevant definitions.  It is always safe to accept things you won't be given, as long as you also accept things you *will* be given.  So function input parameter types can be *wider* than the expected argument types. Additionally, since JavaScript lets you call functions with extra arguments, which are (generally) harmlessly ignored, you can view a function of fewer parameters as accepting *more* things, not less. See [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters).

Let's look at your examples and see why they behave the way they do for:

```
interface Person {
    say(type: "a" | "b"): void;
}
let i: Person;
```

First we have:

```
class Worker0 implements Person {
    say() {
        console.log("okay")
    }
}
i = new Worker0(); i.say("b"); // "okay"
```

That's fine because `Worker0`'s `say()` will just ignore its input. There is no danger with `i.say("b")`.

```
class Worker1 implements Person {
    say(type: string) {
        console.log(type.toUpperCase())
    }
}
i = new Worker1(); i.say("b"); // B
```

That's fine because `Worker1`'s `say()` is happy to accept any `string`.  Since `"a"` and `"b"` are both `string`s, then here is no danger with `i.say("b")`.

```
class Worker2 implements Person {
    say(type: "a" | "b" | "c") {
        console.log(({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 })[type].toFixed())
    }
}
i = new Worker2(); i.say("b"); // 2
```

That's fine because `Worker2`'s `say()` is happy you accept `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"c"`. Since `"a"` and `"b"` are both in that list, there is no danger with `i.say("b")`.

```
class Worker3 implements Person {
    say(type: "a" | "c") {
        console.log(({ a: 1, c: 0 })[type].toFixed())
    }
}
i = new Worker3(); i.say("b"); // RUNTIME ERROR
```

That's an error because `Worker3`'s `say()` does not accept `"b"`. It only accepts `"a"` or `"c"`.  When you call `i.say("b")`, it is passing `"b"` to something that does not expect it, and it is easy for there to be a runtime error, as shown above.  Therefore `Worker3` does not properly implement `Person`, and you get compile time errors.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAVYGcD2ZUDewAkFggJ4AUE5ADlAFyoBECzqAPiwEbMCUTAG44QAEwDcwAL7AANlAioQTTDFxhJwJLIRYsqAOo4YAa1gAGJQFta8q1Ej7V6wiTJU+r4sSR5c8gDpZHABzSmYcEwp+EhkZEFQAXlQwKAB3Q2MzGHNKPnElAPdw3nzUAHpylkjo4C0dPUzTWABGa1soe0cMbDwvYpp6JiwIGHAQzyJvXzB-KCDQ6jp5iBwAVVp6GABhXSg8vljpUCSU9KbslryCkCKKEv4CytQAITrtXX0jZpgAJna7A4IE5evgpgNlkxWOwuMxeJwWEh+F4fH4cIFgmFKARUAgmC0ADSobhMX5EpBMADMqCkfAA2oMoABdAKrABiIAAHlBRAcjvFTqkMt9sr9roVinDHhUqr93g0vllYNSQDZAd1nH1wfdGVC2AjmEjJiRUbN0fNMZRsbj8eSmJZaQzliz2VyeXziHETskhRdleLbpLSk8qgAlNYAOQAKgBJACyAFFUAnQ6GAPKhoA)